# displaying the contents of a vector with a for loop one value displayed

Tags: c++

Hi I am having some trouble with this program. only one value is displayed as a result of the for loop, and the delete function in the program does not work. I'm having trouble thinking my way around this to do it differently.

```
   // dvd title library



#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int adqv, ete, ti;
vector<string> dvdtitle(101);
vector<string>::const_iterator place;
string title, second, third ;


do{cout<< "welcome to your Dvd library!"
&& cout<< "     To add titles enter 1.                              To                        delete titles enter 2.            Type 3 to quit"

 && cin>>adqv;


switch (adqv)
{case 1 : cout<<"Enter the title name"
&& cin >>title
&& cout<<"Enter another title"
&& cin>>second
&& cout <<"Enter a third title"
&&cin>>third;
   break;
case 2: 
cout<<"enter the number of the title to be deleted. starting with 0  then     1"
 && cin>>ete;

break;
case 3:
    {return 0;}
default: cout<<"invalid choice";}

dvdtitle.push_back(title);
dvdtitle.push_back(second);
dvdtitle.push_back(third);
 if (adqv=2)
 dvdtitle.erase(dvdtitle.begin()+ete);

sort(dvdtitle.begin(), dvdtitle.end());

  for ( place = dvdtitle.begin(); place< dvdtitle.end()  ; ++place);

  { cout<< "             These are your titles           ";
  cout<< *place;



  }


}while (adqv !=3);

}
```

Comment: _"I'm having trouble"_ is a pretty vague error description. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: What did you expect with that formatting? It keeps your chances of doing something right pretty low.

Comment: *vector<string> dvdtitle(101);* creates 101 elements in the vector, and then *dvdtitle.push_back(title);* will add this as 102 element and so on.., and then *dvdtitle.erase(dvdtitle.begin()+ete);* will not erase the element you think i would.

Comment: Make it a habit to use `place != dvdtitle.end()` in stead of `<`. Not all iterator types are relationally comparable. Or use a range based for loop.

Comment: @bkVnet Answer below vvvvvvv. May be propose a fix as well.

Comment: `if (adqv=2)` -> `if (adqv==2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The line `for ( place = dvdtitle.begin(); place< dvdtitle.end()  ; ++place);`

Should not contain the semicolon ';' at the end. It acts as a empty body for the loop, when the loop finishes `place` will be equal to `dvdtitle.end()`, a one-past-the-end iterator, when you try to print it afterwards you go out of bounds on the vector.

Comment: now with the delete function  will make a copy of the title to be deleted instead of deleting it

Comment: You always run the code `dvdtitle.push_back(title); dvdtitle.push_back(second); dvdtitle.push_back(third);` regardless of what choice is made. Thus adding 3 items even when the user chose to delete a item.